# SSIS vs. .NET Numerical Precision

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, ssis

Why does SSIS behave differently than t-sql or .NET when rounding numerical or decimal values? i.e why is the 12th number rounded up when the 13th is higher or equal to 5 differently than the other technologies?
What is the workaround?

original value:
7.4382283443836172  - data type: nvarchar(128)

SSIS :
7.438228344383 - data type: casted to decimal(25,12) in derived column

.NET and t-sql:
7.438228344384 - casted in t-sql or ConvertTo.Decimal in .NET

Comment: Looks like SSIS is just truncating or using a different rounding method.

Comment: What .NET and T-SQL types are you using?  How are you validating their values?

Comment: The types are indicated in the original posting. For .NET I am converting a string to decimal (ConvertTo.Decimal) and for T-SQL I am converting an nvarchar(128) to decimal(25,12)